# renaming in one command line, same file which is in multiple folders

Tags: bash, file-rename, mv

I need to rename same file which is in 4 different directories in one command line(bash)...I can't use ";" or bash script.Thanks....I was trying something like:

```
mv folder/{folder1,folder2,...}/file folder/{folder1,folder2,...}/new_name_file
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
$ mkdir foo bar baz
$ touch {foo,bar,baz}/quux
$ find foo bar baz -type f -name quux | while read file; do mv "$file" $(dirname "$file")/xyxxy; done
$ find foo bar baz -type f -name xyxxy
foo/xyxxy
bar/xyxxy
baz/xyxxy
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define more lines at the end part:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                           

while read dir diir; do
    mv $dir $diir
done <<___HERE                                                                                                                                        
/path/to/dir1   /path/to/diir1                                                                                                                        
/path/to/dir2   /path/to/diir2                                                                                                                        
___HERE
```

you can run it in one line :

```
$./script.sh | (Do what you want here)
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
find folder/folder{1,2,3} -type f -name 'file' -exec bash -c 'mv -v {} $(dirname {})/new_name_file' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case you can use:

```
echo folder/{folder1,folder2,...} | xargs -n1 echo |xargs -I% mv %/oldfile %/newfile
```

but a more portable one to rename all files in a subdirectory would be

```
rename(){ #usage rename from_name to_name
    find . -name $1 |xargs -l dirname |xargs -I% mv %/$1 %/$2
}
```